# getter and setter of double array

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I've got a simple code:

```
double Lzakupow[];

Lzakupow[x] = Double.parseDouble(idd);
x++;

UstawLzakupow(Lzakupow);

public void ustawLzakupow(double[] Lzakupow){
    this.Lzakupow = Lzakupow;
}

public double[] Lzakupow(){
    return Lzakupow;
}
```

and when I do

```
Lzakupow = new double[Lzakupow()];
```

I've got type mismatch: cannot convert from double[] to int info.

Where is the problem? Can anyone help me?

Comment: `new array` expect an int (the length of the array). What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: get out dynamic array from asynctask

Comment: I'm not quite familiar with android, yet I feel your code doesn't make sense or follow any logic. can you explain your logic plz?

Comment: What were you trying to achieve when you wrote `Lzakupow = new double[Lzakupow()];`? What do you think this line of code _should_ do?

Comment: You should follow java naming conventions also. Classes start with a capital letter and variables are camelCase where the first letter is lower and each new word is then capital. Like this Class: `SomeClass` Variable: `thisIsSomeVariable`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in `Lzakupow = new double[Lzakupow()];`

Because the Lzakupow() method returns a double array, and you are trying to create a double array of a specific length, which must be an int

Maybe you wanted either:

`Lzakupow = Lzakupow();`

Or

`Lzakupow = new double[Lzakupow.length];`